# Can you pull minimum from a variable given a condition for another variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the data from the min. reproducible example below. I want to update the MinReadyAge variable with the minimum value of ready.data$RetAge from ready.data in which ready.data$Ready == 'Yes'. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Bonus point if there is a way to return "Never Ready" for the case where there is no 'Yes' for any age.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
MinReadyAge <- 1:5

min.age.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,MinReadyAge))

ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        3,3,3,3,3,
        4,4,4,4,4,
        5,5,5,5,5)

RetAge <- rep(seq(from = 65, to = 69, by = 1),5)

Ready <- c("No","No","No","No","No",
           "No","No","No","No","Yes",
           "No","No","No","Yes","Yes",
           "No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes",
           "Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes")

ready.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,RetAge,Ready))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join on the 'min.age.data' after `slice`ing the `min` value of 'RetAge' by 'ID' where the 'Ready' is "Yes"

```
library(dplyr)
ready.data %>% 
   filter(Ready == 'Yes') %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice_min(RetAge) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(ID, MinRetAge = RetAge) %>%
   right_join(min.age.data) %>%
   arrange(ID)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     ID MinRetAge MinReadyAge
#  <dbl>     <dbl>       <int>
#1     1        NA           1
#2     2        69           2
#3     3        68           3
#4     4        67           4
#5     5        65           5
```

---

If we need to update the 'MinRetAge' column

```
 min.age.data <- ready.data %>% 
    filter(Ready == 'Yes') %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice_min(RetAge) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(ID, RetAge) %>% 
    right_join(min.age.data) %>%
    transmute(ID, MinReadyAge = coalesce(RetAge, MinReadyAge)) %>%
    arrange(ID)
```

-output

```
min.age.data
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#     ID MinReadyAge
#  <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1           1
#2     2          69
#3     3          68
#4     4          67
#5     5          65
```

#### data

```
# // as.data.frame(cbind is not needed and it will unnecessarily chage the type
# // cbind by default returns a matrix and matrix can have only a single type
# // instead using data.frame directly
ready.data <- data.frame(ID, RetAge, Ready)
min.age.data <- data.frame(ID, MinReadyAge)
```

Comment: Should I do this in combination with a join to pull it into the "min.age.data" data frame?

Comment: @Ccs The column is created in the data.  You just need to update the object i.e. `ready.data <- ready.data %>%  group_by(ID) %>%...`

Comment: @CcS I updated with a join method as well

Comment: I want the MinRetAge to be in the "min.age.data" data frame, not the "ready.data" data frame. That is, I want to look-up that result and update the min.age.data$MinReadyAge variable. I'm trying to avoid creating a new variable in the ready.data data frame. I guess it wouldn't be too cumbersome to just join the two and then delete the variable, though.

Comment: @CcS In that case just do the join on that dataset.  Please check the updated output